# add new data to json with angular js

Tags: angularjs, json

Hello I am using angular js. Ii try to delete data from my json but when I refresh the page the json file still didn't change. The data I have deleted still there.

I put my json on [myjson.com](http://myjson.com)

```
[
  { 
    "id":1,
    "name": "sarah",
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name": "tommy"
    ]
  }
  {
    "id":2,
    "name": "rian"
    ]
  }
]
```

This is my code for delete the data:

```
 $scope.deleteItem =function(experience){
            var index = $scope.experiences.indexOf(experience);
            alert("Deleting DATA: "+ index);
            $scope.experiences.splice(index,1);
        };
```

Do I need to code php or something? I thought I can delete the file with just code from angularjs. I'm still new here so  please can you tell me.

Comment: A file can only be changed on server using server side code

Comment: @charlietfl  oh okay. so  with this code its still not enough to delete or  update the json?

Comment: No...it is not. You would need to send data to server and modifiy stored version there

Comment: $scope.experiences.splice just remove item from $scope.experiences array in UI. if you want to update json you should update server side json model its better to make a service or something like that and then call it by index or id parameter to remove item from "myjson.com" then if remove function run successfully it will return result after that you can run $scope.experiences.splice to update view